# Can the replicated database be the publisher with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication

I need to setup replication for a Client but their production database server doesn't seem to have the components installed to enable publishing.

Is it possible to setup what should be the subscriber as the publisher and pull changes from the master database? And is this going to cause problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The publisher is local to the data being published and can't be remote.

[image: MSDN overview]

You can have a separate *distributor* of course

You'll have to consider database mirroring perhaps as an alternative or enable replication at the client

Comment: So of the two mirroring or replication at the client which would be better and if I setup the client as the publisher would that mean that the replication is two way?

Comment: @eaglestorm: mirroring is a DR setup, not replication. But it simpler to set up and abuse for your purposes maybe. If you want 2 way data flow then you *need* replication and will have to set it up at the client